# Logo in LaTeX document

Tags: graphics, header-footer, titles, fancyhdr

I don't see any (big) logo on the title page of document class. I'm using the example of `report` in TeXnicCenter.

How can I include a logo on all pages?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

%% Deutsche Anpassungen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-Schriftart für nicht-englische Texte

\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken

%%
\usepackage{a4wide} %%Kleinere Seitenränder = mehr Text pro Zeile.
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%Fancy Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage{longtable} %%Für Tabellen, die eine Seite überschreiten
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Logo.jpg}
}

\title{ABC}
\author{Dipl.-Ing. ABC}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagestyle{plain} %%Ab hier die Kopf-/Fusszeilen: headings / fancy / ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use the pagestyle of fancyhdr and not plain: `pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: Changed but nothing happend

Comment: You won't get a logo on the title page. Add some text after `\pagestyle{fancy}` and look at page 2.

Comment: The default cover pages are cr*p, for a reason, because almost everyone's requirements are different, it would be futile. You need to build your own.

Comment: You naturally need also some text for a second page. On the title page the logo will not show as it uses `\thispagestyle{empty}`. But you can redefine the empty style, see `Redefining plain style` in fancyhdr documentation. Or use the titlepage environment to design your own title page.

Comment: I need logo(graphics ) on title page before title appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The report class uses an `\pagestyle{empty}` for the title page. You need to redefine that page style

```
\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Logo.jpg}}
}
```

This gives a MWE of

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Logo.jpg}}
}

\title{ABC}
\author{Dipl.-Ing. ABC}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: TBH I don’t like this approach. I would prefer to define a new `fancypagestyle`, let’s say `justlogo` and then add `\thispagestyle{justlogo}` directly before `\maketitle`. So if one by any chance needs an empty page, he does not get a bad surprise when applying `\thispagestyle{empty}`.